# Переименование файлов Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

//// Переименовывание файлов. Функция возвращает True если операция переименования прошла успешно.

```
procedure RenameDir(DirFrom, DirTo: string);

var
  shellinfo: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  with shellinfo do
  begin
    Wnd := 0;
    wFunc := FO_RENAME;
    pFrom := PChar(DirFrom);
    pTo := PChar(DirTo);
    fFlags := FOF_FILESONLY or FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_SILENT or
      FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
  end;
  SHFileOperation(shellinfo);
end;

/// /////////////////////////////////// Тут сделал через переменные
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  a, b: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  a := 'C:\Users\tatyana\Desktop\test\1.txt';
  b := 'C:\Users\tatyana\Desktop\Test\New_1.txt';
  RenameDir(a, b);
end;
```

Все работает но:

**Вопрос:** Как подключить **memo1** (Исходящий список путей к файлам) и **memo2** (Выходящий список путей к файлам - с новыми именами).

Нажимаю кнопку и происходит переименование всех файлов из **списка memo1** на те что в **списке memo2**.

**////////////////////// Дополнение из ответов:**

```
function RenameDir(DirFrom, DirTo: string): integer;
var
  shellinfo: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  with shellinfo do
  begin
    Wnd    := 0;
    wFunc  := FO_RENAME;
    pFrom  := PChar(DirFrom);
    pTo    := PChar(DirTo);
    fFlags := FOF_FILESONLY or FOF_ALLOWUNDO or
              FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;

  end;
  result := SHFileOperation(shellinfo);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  a, b: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do begin
    a := Memo1.Lines[i];
    b := Memo2.Lines[i];
   ShowMessage(IntToStr(RenameDir(a, b)))
  end;
end;
```

Comment: уберите первый вызов `RenameDir(a, b);`

Comment: @Igor, Убрала - все равно показывает число 114 в сообщении.

Comment: Что то вы не договариваете `DE_MANYSRC1DEST 0x72 Multiple file paths were specified in the source buffer, but only one destination file path.`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov посмотрите ссылку в моем ответе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795(v=vs.85).aspx

> **pFrom**
>
> Type: PCZZTSTR
>
> Note  This string must be double-null terminated.

то есть

> Учтите, что эта строка должна заканчиваться двумя нулевыми символами

*(то же самое и для `pTo`)*

Эта функция (`SHFileOperation`) может выполнять операции оболочки для нескольких файлов сразу. Имена этих файлов, находятся в буфере, на который указывает `pFrom` (или `pTo`), и разделены в нем нулевыми символами. Чтобы функция знала, где список этих имен файлов заканчивается, в его конце должны стоять два нулевых символа.

До сих пор Вам, очевидно, везло.

Цикл в ответе Антона - правильный, но в самой функции `RenameDir` надо добавить

```
pFrom  := PChar(DirFrom + #0);
pTo    := PChar(DirTo + #0);
```

Comment: Это что означает, то есть ?, я просто не понимаю.

Comment: Интересная особенность

Comment: @Igor, Спасибо Вам. Все заработало. Только странно почему такая особенность в справке майкрософт, справку прочитала.

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  a, b: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do begin
    a := Memo1.Lines[i];
    b := Memo2.Lines[i];
    RenameDir(a, b);
  end;
end;
```

Но нужно, чтобы в Memo1 строк было не больше, чем в Memo2

Comment: Сделал но ничего не переименовывает. Пути точно совпадают. В чем может быть проблема?.

Comment: Нет такого файла, нет прав на переименования, неправильно заполнена структура `shellinfo`... `SHFileOperation` это функция и она возвращает 0, если операция прошла успешно или код ошибки при ошибке. В чем у вас проблема можно сказать проанализировав этот код

Comment: Так а без memo работает, когда указываю пути напрямую.

Comment: `ShowMessage(a + ' -> ' + b);` - ?

Comment: @Igor, Сделала вот так и результат сообщения вот такой   C:\Users\tatyana\Desktop\test\1.txt -> C:\Users\tatyana\Desktop\Test\New_1.txt

Comment: @Татьяна Код ошибки принципиально сообщать не хотите?

Comment: `function RenameDir(DirFrom, DirTo: string): integer; ... result := SHFileOperation(shellinfo); end;`

Comment: `ShowMessage(IntToStr(RenameDir(a, b)));`

Comment: @Igor, У меня показывает число 114 в сообщении. Код полный добавила в вопрос - посмотрите.